# Laravel datatable date format doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I'm using datatable to display data include `postingdate` column, I need to change the format of `postingdate` column, as I found some tutorials about this and used the code below put when run. I got error message and table doesn't appear.

The error message:

> DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Code:

```
$users = Checks::select(['details', 'postingdate', 'description', 'amount', 'type', 'slip', 'vendor_id', 'category_id']);

return Datatables::of($users)->editColumn('postingdate', function ($user) {
return $user->postingdate->format('d-m-Y')})->make(true);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$users=Checks::select(['details','postingdate','description','amount','type','slip','vendor_id','category_id']);
return Datatables::of($users)->editColumn('postingdate', function ($user) 
{
    //change over here
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($user->postingdate) );
})->make(true);
```

Comment: Doing this breaks the order functionality. It orders by day first. How I can solve this? In datatables core you can set the attribute data-order to international format what makes ordering by year first what is correct. But with this library don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this problem, you need to return two field to the UI, one used for display and one for sorting.

**Controller**

```
return Datatables::of(User::with('roles')->get())
            ->editColumn('created_at', function ($user) {
                return [
                    'display' => Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->format('d/m/Y'),
                    'timestamp' => $user->created_at->timestamp
                ];
            })
            ....
```

**UI**

```
          columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id', visible: false},
                    {data: 'name', name: 'name', orderable: true},    
                    {
                        name: 'created_at.timestamp',
                        data: {
                            _: 'created_at.display',
                            sort: 'created_at.timestamp'
                        }
                    },
                ],
```

In the UI, `created_at` is the name of the first param of `editColumn`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$users=Checks::select(['details', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(checks.postingdate, '%d-%M-%Y %H:%i') as postingdate"),'description','amount','type','slip','vendor_id','category_id']);

return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
```